# Meaning of green symbol - SQL developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I use SQL Developer and when I updated one of my trigger, there is a green symbol that appears and I do not understand what it means.

[image: Exemple on SQL Developper]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It means, it has been compiled for debug.

Click compile and it will remove the arrow.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !